# Changing workflow of an already published form

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

When i check the formsflow application,i found that user with designer role can change the workflow of an already published form.if he do so , what happens to the existing submitted application and task? will it affect the existing task?
Will the user has the permission to edit the submitted form?

Comment: The new changes will impact only the yet to submit forms from client. It will not impact the existing task in any way.